# Configuring ActiveMQ: How to Send a Message to an Apache ActiveMQ Queue with Node.js

Tags: node.js, activemq-classic

I have a JAVA api which needs to consume data from ActiveMQ.

Client has provided me the host,Port and API key details.

Im a newby in this ActiveMQ and need suggestion on how to establish the initial queue connection since the queue works on tcp protocol.

I was suggested to use one of the client libraries supported by activeMQ in various languages

Currently i am referring :  http://activemq.apache.org/cross-language-clients.html

Need suggestion on how to configure or execute (if i use "How to Send a Message to an Apache ActiveMQ Queue with Node.js" from the above link) on the below code.

```
const stompit = require('stompit');

stompit.connect({ host: 'localhost', port: 61613 }, (err, client) => {
const frame = client.send({ destination: 'SampleQueue' });

frame.write('Simples Assim');

frame.end();

client.disconnect();
 });
```

Assuming i don't have any Node environment setup in my machine.

Answer (score 0):

If the endpoint that is exposed to you is using the standard TCP based endpoint for the broker then you need to use a client that connects via the TCP layer using the OpenWire protocol which is the native protocol for the ActiveMQ JMS client and the C++ ActiveMQ-CPP client as well as the NMS.ActiveMQ .NET client.  You cannot use a STOMP client or other protocol client to talk directly to an OpenWire TCP transport connector.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to or send messages to ActiveMQ using the STOMP protocol. Just use the example from https://github.com/gdaws/node-stomp
 (and you definitely need to install Nodejs on the machine that will be running that script).

I'm not sure of how your workflow is with the Java API, but if that API sends some message to ActiveMQ and you need to deal with that message, you can use `stompit`. All you need to do is subscribe to the queue in which the message is stored. If you need to send a reply message, you can do so as well to any queue you wish.